# Event Arrival visualisation

Tags: data-visualization

I have a streaming set of visualisations (time stamp of each event) which tend to be grouped when arriving at the queue. I was wondering if I could go from the graph at the top to the density graph below. Is there a particular algorithm that already does this?

The simplest solution I can think of is binning the number of events within a time interval. There must be better solutions though.

[image]

Comment: Could you post some subset of your data so we have something to experiment with?

Answer (score 1):

I think binning events within a (rolling) time interval and calculating the frequency within each bin is your best bet for this.

Comment: A kernel density plot could do this, I should think.